# work around inconsistencies knockout checked binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'm struggling without the knockout checked binding. See this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/u8h4Z/).

My 2 problems questions are:

1. How can I have the 'selected value' be a rich JS object with checkbox/radio inputs? With other input types and bindings, the selected value can be a rich type. But checkbox/radio buttons can only be a simple string value.

Generally speaking I have several lookup lists from the DB which are arrays of maps. For example in the fiddle example I have a list of countries:

```
[
  {countryName: "UK", countryPopulation: 650000000},
  {countryName: "USA", countryPopulation: 1700000000},
  {countryName: "Canada", countryPopulation: 320000000}
]
```

For almost every form input that I have I will want the 'selected value' to be a rich JS object. In the radio button example from fiddle, I want the selectedCustomerType to be:

```
{label: 'Acquiring', value: 'A'}
```

and not just:

```
'A'
```

1. Initializing the radio button also doesn't seem to work. I can get the view to look right with the JS code on line 15:

   self.selectedCustomerType = ko.observable(self.availableCustomerTypes()[0].value);

(It's unfortunate I have to initialize with self.availableCustomerTypes()[0].value instead of just using self.availableCustomerTypes()[0].)

But even though the view looks right the html binding doesn't show anything (line 21 of the HTML).

```
<div>
  You have chosen customer type
  <span data-bind:"value: selectedCustomerType()"></span>.
</div>
```

But in the output the selectedCustomerType is not displayed. How do I initialize the selectedCustomerType correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With KO 3.0, you can now use the `checkedValue` binding along with the `checked binding to specify specifically what the value will be (rather than setting the`value` attribute of the element and using its value as a string).

So, you can now do:

```
data-bind='checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedCustomerType'
```

With that change, you would now be able to initialize it with just `self.availableCustomerTypes()[0]`.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8GJpF/

For additional info, look for `checkedValue` here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

Comment: Thanks. That gets me 95% there. It got me on track to dig into the somewhat mysterious $data variable. However, unfortunately in your fiddle example, note that <span data-bind:"value: selectedCustomerType()"></span> on line 21 never gets bound or updated. I'd like it initially set and it will change when the selected radio button changes. Why is that not working?  Thanks again!

Comment: Another thing...when you inspect the actual DOM in the fiddle you provided, looking at the actual radio <input> tags value gets set to the *string* [object Object], but not the actual object itself. In either case, we actual want value still set to 'A' or 'N', but selectedCustomerType to be the underlying object.

Comment: I updated the fiddle. You can use `attr: { value: value }` to ensure that the `value` attribute is set appropriately.  For the other issue, you need to use the `text` binding on a `span` and need to use `data-bind=` rather than `data-bind:`